# Is there a way to call a spring cloud app using angular

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am developing a spring cloud application, but the front-end is in angular. Is there a way to call a spring boot app which has a spring cloud gateway with eureka service discovery, using angular app.

The discovery server registers my spring boot app as well as the gateway-service, and I want to call my rest services using angular.

I tried giving the service-name in http call, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You need to know the hostname/ip address of spring cloud gateway app

Comment: ok, so do I need to register the gateway service with eureka?

Comment: it needs to be a eureka client at the least. But discovery doesn't leak out to HTTP clients